# How to use the expression "loser hands"?

Tags: idioms, semantics, idiom-meaning

I heard sentences which involved the expression "loser hands", e.g. "this is one of the loser hands" (with reference to some concept which someone had expressed perplexity about).

- Which is the correct usage of the epression "loser hands" and could you give me any example?

Comment: By loser hands, do you mean "a person who fails something"?

Comment: The original expression was: "This is one of the loser hands, it's mostly the strangest thing in the Book" , with some references to a "tension" which forced the author to change his theories, in order to avoid the tension.

Comment: "Looser hand" is almost certainly referring to a "hand" of cards in poker or a similar card game.  It's a hand with low-valued cards that are unlikely to be able to be played effectively.

Answer (score 4):

A little hard to tell without specific context, but typically a "loser hand" or "losing hand" is from card games such as Poker, where it can be any hand of cards which loses to the "winning hand."

Comment: Except that you can often look at your "hand" and tell it's a loser before the round of play even starts.

Comment: True, but what I meant was needing context from the OP about where they had read the sentence.